# To construct a continuous map on compact metric spaces (cf. Gromov-Hausdorff Limit)

Tags: metric-geometry, gromov-hausdorff-limit

This is about Gromov Hausdorff limit on compact metric spaces

(Reference A course in metric geometry - Burago Burago and Ivanov, 268p. EXE 7.5.8)

Definition : $d_{GH}(X,Y)<\epsilon $ if there exists a metric space $Z$ s.t. $$ f: X\rightarrow Z,\ g: Y\rightarrow Z$$ are isometries onto its image and $$ d_H(f(X), g(Y))< \epsilon $$ 
 Here $d_H$ is a Hausdorff distance. That is, $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $f(X)$ contains $g(Y)$ and vice versa.

Definition 2 : If $X_n$ is a sequence of compact metric spaces and if $X$ is a compact metric space, then $X_n\rightarrow_{GH}X$ if $$ d_{GH}(X_n,X)\rightarrow 0 $$

Problem : If $(X_n,d_n)\rightarrow (X,d)$, where $X$ is a standard unit ball in ${\bf R}^n$, then there exists continuous map 
$f_n :X_n\rightarrow X$ s.t. $f_n$ is $\epsilon_n$-isometry and $\epsilon_n\rightarrow 0$ ($\epsilon_n$-isometry : any point in $X$ has distance $<\epsilon_n$ 
from $f_n(X_n)$ and $\sup_{x,\ y}\ 
|d_n(x,y)-d(f_n(x),f_n(y)) | <\epsilon_n$)

Proof : For $\delta$, there exists $N$ s.t. $n\geq N$ implies that $d_{GH}(X_n,X)<\delta$

That is for $n$ there exists a metric space $(Z,d_Z)$ s.t. $$ f: X_n\rightarrow Z,\ g: X\rightarrow Z $$
and $$ d_H(f(X_n),g(X))<\delta $$

Here we want to construct $ F : X_n \rightarrow X
$ For $z\in Z',\ Z':=f(X_n)\cap g(X)$ and $x=f^{-1}(z),\ g(y)=z$, $F(x)=y$

For $z\in f(X_n)-g(X)$ we want to find a suitable point in $Z'$ For instance if ther exists unique $z'$ s.t. $d(z,Z')=d(z,z'),\ z'\in Z'$, then $F(f^{-1} (z))=g^{-1}(z') $.

And note that $F$ is $\delta$-isometry and continuous.

But this may not happen since $z'$ is not unique So how can we construct ? Thank
you in anticipation.

Comment: If $X$ is the *unit* ball, what is the significance of $r$? What do you mean by $B_{r + \epsilon}$? And what do you mean by "$f(X)$ is convex"? I am not aware of any concept of convexity in arbitrary metric spaces. Do you mean compact instead? If so, then $x'$ exists, but it is not necessarily unique. Also the sentence beginning "But we convince this ..." makes no sense at all. I have no Idea what you mean by it.

Comment: I will add some

Comment: And since $f$ is isometric then $f(X)$ is still convex in arbitrary metric space : In any two points $y_i$ in $f(X)$ there exists a shortest path $c$ between $x_i:=f^{-1}(y_i)$ So $$l(f\circ c)=l(c)=d_0(x_1,x_2)=d(y_1,y_2) $$

Comment: Again, how do you define the phrase "$f(X)$ is convex"? $f(X)$ is a subset of an arbitrary metric space. What does it mean to say that a subset of this space is "convex"? If $Z$ were an $\Bbb R$ module, then I would know what you mean. But for arbitrary metric spaces, I am unaware of any definition.

Comment: I see. I want to emphasize that there exist several points $x'$ I will fix it.

Comment: That makes more sense. Just to be clear, though, are you given a particular $r$ and particular isometry $f\ :\ B_r(0) \to Z$, or is there such an isometry for any value of $r$ - in particular for $r + \epsilon$? If the latter is true, then you could invert that isometry to embed $Y$ in $\Bbb R^n$, and apply the proof already given.

Comment: I wanted to write simpler but it is difficult. So I rewrite

Comment: It would have been better to have just answered the question instead of completely rewriting the post. Now I have additional questions. Is that really the entire definition of $d_{GH}$? Because it seems to me that for any $X, Y$ and $\epsilon$, you should always be able to build a $Z$ and isometries $f, g$ with $d_H(f(X), g(Y)) < \epsilon$.

Comment: Yes as far as I know. And if there exists such $Z$, then we say $d_{GH}(X,Y)<\epsilon $. If $\epsilon$ is large, for instance it is a large constant depending on ${\rm diam}\ X,\ {\rm diam}\ Y$, we can build such $Z$

Comment: And to first question, $f : B_r(0) \rightarrow Z$ is an isometry for a fixed $r$

Comment: Never mind my question about $d_{GH}$. I was thinking of the wrong definition of the distance between two sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I note from the definition of GH-convergence that $X$ is compact, so we are talking about the closed unit ball. That makes things easier. You cannot guarantee a unique closest element $x' \in f(X)$ to $x$, so you need to find a means to choose between multiple elements.

One way is consider the points $a_k = (\delta_{1k}, \delta_{2k}, \ldots, \delta_{nk})$, where $\delta_{ij}$ is the Kronecker delta. Let $$A_x = \{ z \in f(X) \mid d(x, z) = d(x, f(X))\}$$
If $d_x = d(x, f(X))$, then $A_x = f(X) \cap \{ z \in Z\mid d(z, x) = d_x\}$ is the intersection of a compact set and a closed set, and so must be compact.

Define $C_0 = f^{-1}(A_x)$, then $C_0$ is a closed subset of the compact set $X$, and thus also compact. For each $k, 0 < k \le n$, define $d_k = d(a_k, C_{k-1})$ and

$$C_k = \{ t \in C_{k-1}\mid d(t, a_k) = d_k\}.$$

A similar argument shows that $C_k$ is compact for all $k$. Since $C_{k-1}$ is compact, it contains points $t$ such that $d(t, a_k) = d_k$, so $C_k$ is not empty for any $k$.

Now the points in $C_n$ are all at a distance $d_k$ from $a_k$ for all $k$. If we consider a point $(t_1, ..., t_n)$, then these conditions supply equations $$R + 1 - 2t_k = d_k^2$$
where $R = \sum_k t_k^2$. Solving the equations for $t_k$ and substituting into the expression for $R$ yields a quadratic in $R$ which has at most two solutions. Since $C_n$ is not empty, there must be at least one positive solution. If there are two, we pick the larger. The value of $R$ then completely determines the values of $t_k$, and therefore a unique point $t' \in C_n$. Define $F(x) = f(t')$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Hi, can you elaborate a bit on why this map is continuous?

Comment: Because $d_0 := d_x$ varies continuously with $x$, each $d_k$ varies continuously with $d_i$ for $i < k$, and thus continuously with $x$, The quadratic equation in $R$ I mentioned is $4R = \sum_k (R+1-d_k^2)^2$, whose higher solution varies continuously with the $d_i$, and therefore with $x$. And thus the $t_k$ and then $t'$ must also vary continuously with $x$, and since $f$ is continuous, therefore $F$ has to be as well.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I think the issue I am having is seeing why $d_{1}$ (and the higher $d_{i}$) varies continuously with $d_{0}$. Given $x, y$, we can define $C_{0}^{x}$ and $C_{0}^{y}$ as in the problem, and then we have $d_{1}^{x} = d(y_{1}, C_{0}^{x})$, $d_{1}^{y} = d(y_{1}, C_{0}^{y}).$ Continuity is saying that for any $r > 0,$ we can find $\delta > 0$ so that if $d(x, y) < \delta,$ we have $|d_{1}^{x} - d_{1}^{y}| < r.$ I can see that $|d_{1}^{x} - d_{1}^{y}|$ is bounded by $d(C_{0}^{x}, C_{0}^{y}),$ but I don't see why $C_{0}^{x}$ and $C_{0}^{y}$ should be close (although it is intuitive).

Comment: @HKLee - Understand that the metrics in play here are the one on $Z$ and the euclidean metric in $\Bbb R^n$. $d^H_Z(A_x, A_y) \le d_Z(x,y)$ by the triangle inequality. $C_0^x = f^{-1}(A_x),  C_0^y = f^{-1}(A_y)$, where $f : X = B_1(0) \to Z$ is an isometry with $f(X)$. Where $d_Z^H$ is the Hausdorff distance between sets in $Z$, not the Gromov Hausdorff distance.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I was thinking of using $d(C_{0}^{x}, C_{0}^{y}) = \inf_{x' \in C_{0}^{x}, y' \in C_{0}^{y}} d(x', y')$, which should be bounded above by the Hausdorff distance $d_{X}^{H}(C_{0}^{x}, C_{0}^{y}),$ which is in turn equal to $d_{Z}^{H}(A_{x}, A_{y})$ (because $f$ is an isometric embedding of $X$). If I use the triangle inequality here I get  $d(C_{0}^{x}, C_{0}^{y}) \leq d_{Z}(x, y) + d(x, f(X)) + d(y, f(Y)),$ which isn't quite what you want (especially as you let $d(x, y) \to 0$).